# Changing value of column

Tags: c#, sql, methods, datagridview, parameters

I want make a Update, more if i call Search method for fill grid and call Update method after its inverting value of second and third column and updating on SQL Server.

Ex:

Click Search Button its fill the grid:

Jhon 2 3

Snow 4 5

White 6 7

Click update Button and click on search button again

Jhon 3 2

Snow 5 4

White 7 6

```
public void Update(int param_idficha, int param_rgp, int param_quant, double param_peso, string param_date, string param_peixe)
    {
        vsql = "UPDATE cadastro SET PESO = @PESO, QUANTIDADE = @QUANTIDADE WHERE ID_FICHA = @ID_FICHA and PEIXE LIKE @PEIXE";
        SqlCommand objcmd = null;

        if (this.Conectar())
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime dtParam = DateTime.Parse(param_date);
                objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);

                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID_FICHA", param_idficha));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RGP", param_rgp));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PEIXE", param_peixe));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PESO", param_peso));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUANTIDADE", param_quant));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATA_REGISTRO", dtParam));

                objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Desconectar();
            }
        }
    }
```

Search and Fill Grid Method:

```
  private void btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       if (txtb_idFicha.Text.Length > 0)
       {
           int i = Convert.ToInt32(txtb_idFicha.Text);

           _peixe_list.Clear();
           _peso_list.Clear();
           _quant_list.Clear();


           objSQL.Search_IDFicha(i, _peixe_list, _quant_list, _peso_list);

           dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

           for (int j = 0; j < _peixe_list.Count; j++)
           {
               string[] rows = { _peixe_list[j], _quant_list[j], _peso_list[j] };

               dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rows);
           }
       }

       else
           MessageBox.Show("Preencha o campo N° Ficha", " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);



   }
```

Update Method:

```
private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       int param_id = Convert.ToInt32(txtb_idFicha.Text);
       int param_rgp = Convert.ToInt32(txtb_RGP.Text);

       string DateTimesql = myDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

       _peixe_list.Clear();
       _quant_list.Clear();
       _peso_list.Clear();

       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
       {

           if (row.Cells.Count >= 2 && row.Cells[0].Value != null)
           {
               _peixe_list.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
               _peso_list.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
               _quant_list.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
           }

       }


       for (int x = 0; x < _peixe_list.Count; x++)
              objSQL.Update(param_id, param_rgp, Convert.ToInt32(_quant_list[x]), Convert.ToDouble(_peso_list[x]), DateTimesql, _peixe_list[x]);

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you do the following to accomplish the task.

I am assuming that the **Search Button its fill the grid** is running okay. Than on update

Instead of

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {

       if (row.Cells.Count >= 2 && row.Cells[0].Value != null)
       {
           _peixe_list.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
           _peso_list.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
           _quant_list.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
       }

   }
```

You can do the same thing which u did in search but with small change of

```
objSQL.Search_IDFicha(i, _peixe_list, _quant_list, _peso_list);
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
for (int j = 0; j < _peixe_list.Count; j++)
{
   string[] rows = { _peixe_list[j], _peso_list[j],  _quant_list[j] };
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rows);
}
```

Here we have reordered second and third column and to save we will again follow the same procedure of updating which you have done

```
for (int x = 0; x < _peixe_list.Count; x++)
    objSQL.Update(param_id, param_rgp, Convert.ToDouble(_peso_list[x]), Convert.ToInt32(_quant_list[x]), DateTimesql, _peixe_list[x]);
```